# HTML audio tag (Recognizes audio file but wont play it)

Tags: html, audio

I am using the `HTML audio tag` to play music which users upload to my web application (project). when using `xampp` as my local server everything is fine, but when using `filezilla` theres a problem.

The audio file is successfully uploaded and recognized but the HTML audio player wont play the song. Any ideas why?

```
<audio controls>
<source src="user/videos/<?php echo $video;?>">
```

here's a link to a test file to make it clearer

http://kunet.kingston.ac.uk/k1335948/test.php

test file code:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="10183.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: `xxamp` <-- are you sure?

Comment: We'll need more info; do some debugging approach, please.

Comment: i meant xampp, (typo)

Comment: I've posted a link to a test file so you can understand better

Comment: well, and what does your browser tell you? Many browsers (firefox,chrome,opera,...) come with very intuitive web dev/debugger tools.

Comment: I'm using chrome, and it doesn't output any errors, it seems to be fine but it just wont play the file. Have a look at the link I posted, it may become clearer.

Comment: Your webserver seems to have difficulty in serving mp3 files. Try re-uploading the mp3 with a different filename and make changes to your code.

Comment: Where is this `10183.mp3` file? It say 404.

Comment: I've done that before multiple times but no change. Also when I inspect the page, the `mp3` file's status is `pending`, but when using `xampp` it says "206". Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Dai in my root folder with the `test.php` file. Where do you see the 404 error?

Comment: `http://kunet.kingston.ac.uk/k1335948/10183.mp3` accessing this link shows 'pending' for a few minutes then 404. You may want to check whether your school has forbidden / intercepted outgoing media files (schools do that to prevent abuse their bandwidth). Try using a different file extension, if you are lucky that they do not check for mime types, then it should play. If not, switch to a different hosting service.

Comment: @Dai thought so at first, but i have three audio files that actually play when using filezilla. But anything else uploaded since does not play.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the filetype attribute `type="audio/mpeg"` in the `source` tag:

```
<audio controls>
        <source src="10183.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

addition/edit: Plus the mp3 file doesn't seem to be there or corrupted, at least it can't be accessed via the direct link...

Comment: I've just added it but it hasn't made a difference. It works perfectly fine when I'm using `xampp` even without the `type`.

Comment: see the addition to my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't print screen my files but it is definitely there. And its not corrupted because the same file works when I use `xampp`.